# Request.get suddenly started hitting "Temporary failure in name resolution" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-requests, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a script that scrapes new chapters from a specific novel on ncode.syosetu.com every week, I need the text for tts, but this last week I suddenly started getting an error from it when it runs.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ncode.syosetu.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /n6371es/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f21b8d64f28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

I can access the site in Chrome but ping and tracert get "Request timed out", tracert gets the first 9 or so hops but then it only gets "Request timed out" for the rest.

I also tried using https://www.site24x7.com/ping-test.html to ping the site and it only once got a response on the Johannesburg - ZA location.

I tried adding a User-Agent to the request.get call in a header but that didn't help. I have also tried different VPN locations, tuning off the VPN, and pausing my firewall but none helped.

I don't know if it is related but I did have an issue with my internet connection recently, but all I did to fix it was disable then enable my ethernet in Network Connections then uninstall and re-install my VPN.

I have read about the /etc/resolv.conf but I am assuming that would not affect the windows command prompt's ability to ping the site. But just for reference all that is in the file is the WSL comments on how to stop the auto generation.

Is there some way to be able to get requests to the site working again or some other way to get the text from a specific page that would work?
I'd also just kind of want to know if anyone else is able to ping ncode.syosetu.com successfully?

Update:

I have tried to run a simple interactive python3 requests.get in WSL to google.ca and am hitting the same error. I also tried the same command on my work computer, but to ncode.syosetu.com, and it worked there. So I guess the issue on with my computer/internet. Though even on my work computer I could not ping or tracert ncode.syosetu.com.

I also tried:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=1000))
s.get('https://ncode.syosetu.com/n6371es/')
```

but still got the Max retries exceeded with url (Caused by Temporary failure in name resolution)

Comment: The code `s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=1000))
s.get('https://ncode.syosetu.com/n6371es/')
` works for me

Comment: Did you try connecting with the hotspot with the internet of your mobile phone? To see if the problem is with the network

Comment: Thanks for checking the code work. I have not tried using phone mobile hotspot, my computer doesn't have Wi-Fi but I was able to tether to it. I tried the requests again using my mobile network but still got the same error (for both ncode.syosetu.com and google.ca). Also just for reference I have a different provider for mobile vs home internet.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to @Caridorc comments.
I tested the request using my mobile internet and confirmed that the internet provider was not the issue. That made me think that not being able to ping/tracert to the site might have been misleading me so I installed requests in the Windows cmd and the request worked there. So the issue had to with WSL. I looked into /etc/resolv.conf and set `nameserver 8.8.8.8` then the request started working in WSL again. There were a couple steps to get the change to stick but I think the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the issue was with WSL, for some reason it seemed to have lost the ability to access the internet.

I found the fix in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420.

The fix was to:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
(in powershell) wsl --shutdown
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
```

This basically told WSL to stop regenerating the /etc/resolv.conf, restart WSL to apply the /etc/wsl.conf changes, remove the dead link /etc/resolv.conf, then update the DNS with a new /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: obligatory "this fixed it for me". Was using the same code another person was using to call for Azure's openai services and gave the same error as OP after 7 minutes.

Comment: update>[: this worked for me to use Azure services, but broke pip services